# GUI to controll focus and grid of an electron beam

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

When I try to change the value of focus or grid in the UI, I get an error: integer argument expected got function (or something like that, I can´t remember the exact wording I got in the lab). So the function changevalue() doesn´t work because the argument (e.g. gridlb) has the type "function". Why does it has the type function and how can I change it to an integer?

```
import visa
import ftdiwrapper as ft
import time
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

index = 1
h = ft.FT_Open(index)

def init():
    ft.FT_Write(h, 0x51)
    ft.FT_Write(h, 0x5f)

def controlon():
    ft.FT_Write(h, b"\x20\x01")

def changevalue(param, valuelb, valuehb):
    ft.FT_Write(h, bytes([0x32, param, valuelb, valuehb]))


init()
controlon()

changevalue(0x00, 0x00, 5*10) #energy
changevalue(0x01, 0x00, 0xe4) #filament

focuslb0 = 0x00
focushb0 = 0x00
changevalue(0x03, focushb0, focuslb0) #focus
focuslb = focuslb0
focushb = focushb0

gridlb0 = 0x00
gridhb0 = 0x00
changevalue(0x02, gridlb0, gridhb0) # grid
gridlb = gridlb0
gridhb = gridhb0

def gridplus():
    global gridlb, gridhb
    if gridlb <= 240:
        gridlb += 15
    elif gridlb == 255:
        gridlb = 0
        gridhb += 1
    #print('Grid: ', gridlb, gridhb)
    changevalue(0x02, gridlb, gridhb)
    tk.Label(root, text = gridlb).grid(row=1, column=4)
    tk.Label(root, text = gridhb).grid(row=1, column=5)

def gridminus():
    global gridlb, gridhb
    if gridlb >= 15:
        gridlb -= 15
    elif gridlb == 0:
        gridlb = 255
        gridhb -= 1
    #print('Grid: ', gridlb, gridhb)
    changevalue(0x02, gridlb, gridhb)
    tk.Label(root, text = gridlb).grid(row=1, column=4)
    tk.Label(root, text = gridhb).grid(row=1, column=5)

def focusplus():
    global focuslb, focushb
    if focuslb <= 240:
        focushb += 15
    elif focuslb == 255:
        focuslb = 0
        focushb += 1
    #print('Focus: ', focuslb, focushb)
    changevalue(0x03, focuslb, focushb)
    tk.Label(root, text = focuslb).grid(row=0, column=4)
    tk.Label(root, text = focushb).grid(row=0, column=5)

def focusminus():
    global focuslb, focushb
    if focuslb >= 15:
        focuslb -= 15
    elif focuslb == 0:
        focuslb = 255
        focushb -= 1
    #print('Focus: ', focuslb, focushb)
    changevalue(0x03, focuslb, focushb)
    tk.Label(root, text = focuslb).grid(row=0, column=4)
    tk.Label(root, text = focushb).grid(row=0, column=5)

def gridhb():
    global focuslb, focushb
    gridhb = float(G_hb.get())
    changevalue(0x03, gridlb, gridhb)
    tk.Label(root, text = gridhb).grid(row=1, column=5)

def focushb():
    global focuslb, focushb
    focushb = float(F_hb.get())
    changevalue(0x03, focuslb, focushb)
    tk.Label(root, text = focushb).grid(row=0, column=5)


labelF = tk.Label(root, text = "Focus:").grid(row=0, column=0)

Button_Fplus = tk.Button(root, text = "+", command = focusplus)
Button_Fplus.grid(row=0, column=2)

Button_Fminus = tk.Button(root, text = "-", command = focusminus)
Button_Fminus.grid(row=0, column=3)


labelG = tk.Label(root, text = "Grid:")
labelG.grid(row=1, column=0)

Button_Gplus = tk.Button(root, text = "+", command = gridplus)
Button_Gplus.grid(row=1, column=2)

Button_Gminus = tk.Button(root, text = "-", command = gridminus)
Button_Gminus.grid(row=1, column=3)


F_hb = tk.Entry(root)
G_hb = tk.Entry(root)
F_hb.bind('<Return>', focushb)
G_hb.bind('<Return>', gridhb)
F_hb.grid(row=0, column=1)
G_hb.grid(row=1, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: the title of your question, should be a question

Comment: `gridlb0 = 0x00`. `0x00` is not an integer, and `gridlb = gridlb0`. What is it supposed to mean? if you are trying to multiply you need to use `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears in your code you have used gridhb as both a variable and as a function.

See the section starting with

```
def gridhb():
```

Looks like you'll have the same problem with focushb:

```
def focushb():
```

Rename those and the references to them (like here):

```
F_hb.bind('<Return>', focushb)
G_hb.bind('<Return>', gridhb)
```